# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset on Tomcat Only

Tags: java, rest, tomcat7, socketexception

I know this has been asked before and I have tried looking at, at least 30 solutions on stackoverflow if not more, but nothing has worked so far.

I have a tomcat server which is querying into a REST api to fetch and store data. This is to avoid having to query for the data to the remote API every single time my app wants to load the data. The data changes only once in a while and hence this effort. 
I have a simple code to connect

```
final URL url = new URL("https://remote.site.com/api/request?apikey=<some-key>");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
connection.connect();
final InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
final Gson gson = new Gson();
MyJSONResponse myJSONResponse = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, MyJSONResponse.class);
```

When I run this code from a Tomcat7 server on my MacBook it runs perfectly fine. I get the JSON and all is hunky dory. So I went ahead and ran this from inside the Tomcat7 server on my Ubuntu and I almost immediately get the SocketException.

I will concede that the data is a bit long, but I would expect it to wait for a few seconds before throwing this exception. But this exception is thrown on the line

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

which doesn't make sense to me.
To test further, I made a single class program containing just these lines of code and printing out the input stream I get from the remote api and ran this on my Ubuntu box and it runs perfectly fine. So there is nothing wrong with the Ubuntu box and it's internet connectivity. The Tomcat Server seems to be messing up something here. 
I have been trying to do multiple things for 4-5 hours now with resetting the connection, not closing it in the finally block and other things but nothing seems to work. 
Any help would really be appreciated. 
Thanks

Edit: 
Adding logs for timeout:

```
*** Init called
May 22, 2016 11:23:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://www.data.gov.in:443: Connection reset
May 22, 2016 11:23:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://www.data.gov.in:443
May 22, 2016 11:23:22 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://www.data.gov.in:443: Connection reset
May 22, 2016 11:23:22 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://www.data.gov.in:443
May 22, 2016 11:23:24 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://www.data.gov.in:443: Connection reset
May 22, 2016 11:23:24 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://www.data.gov.in:443
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at com.soulpatch.jersey.DataFetcher.init(DataFetcher.java:47)
    at com.soulpatch.jersey.DataFetcher.getBloodBanks(DataFetcher.java:86)
    at com.soulpatch.jersey.resources.BloodBanksResource.getBloodBanks(BloodBanksResource.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: No, it is thrown by `connection.connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the site that I was hitting was the culprit. My server seems to work properly when I hit https://www.google.com.
So I believe it has to do with the SSL certificate resolution on my Tomcat.

Comment: No, it has to do with the target server being slow in the SSL handshake. Nothing to do with your Tomcat. I doubt that a certificate has even been received yet. Your timeouts are pretty aggressive. I would at least double them.

Comment: I went ahead and used the following code to increase the timeouts to 30s. (I changed to the apache HttpClient) : `final HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
            final RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setSocketTimeout(30000)
                    .setConnectTimeout(30000)
                    .build();` it still gives me the same error. I have updated the question with the whole stacktrace. If you see, the time for retry is very short.Feels like it barely waits for the connection to respond. Works perfectly on a browser.

Comment: You may never be able to fix it. It may be allergic to Java user-agents for example, or to the TLS protocol versions supported by your Java.

Comment: since you mention the TLS protocol. Their FAQs section has a certificate for SSL authentication that I was allowed to download. It's a .p7b file. I don't know what to do with it. But do you think configuring that could help this situation?

Comment: Also, when I create a standalone simple java class and put this code in and output the stream as a string, it seems to work completely fine. When I run it on the same Tomcat7 on my macbook, it runs fine. But if I run it on my Ubuntu machine, it fails. I think the fact that it runs on a Tomcat on my MacBook will rule out the allergy to Java user-agents point right? But the p7b certificate could still hold a clue. I am not sure.